# Access $scope in different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am doing my first steps with AngularJS and have a pretty basic question. I have an overview page with some products and want a detail view for each of these products. Here is the relevant code from my controllers:

```
shop.controller('OverviewController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Overview', function($scope, $location, Overview){
    console.log($scope.currentDetail); //always undefined
    $scope.overview = Overview.get();
    $scope.showDetails = function(product){
        $scope.currentDetail = product;
        console.log($scope.currentDetail); //output as expected
        $location.path("/productDetail");
    }
}
]);

shop.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log($scope.currentDetail);
}
]);
```

The relevant part from the overview page is like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in overview.product" ng-click="showDetails(product);">

        <td>
            {{product.DESCRIPTION}}
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Problem is that the the output of    console.log($scope.currentDetail); is always undefined. I think I am missing some basic concept of the $scope here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not forget, that every controller has own `$scope`.

You can use shared service for case, where you want pass some values from one controller to another.

For example:

```
angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("mySharedService", function(){
    var mySharedService = {};

    mySharedService.values = {};

    mySharedService.setValues = function(params){
        mySharedService.values = params;
    }

      return mySharedService; 
});
```

And after inject it into any controller.

```
function OverviewController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.changeProductValue = function(value){
        mySharedService.setValues(value);  
    }
}

function DetailController($scope, mySharedService) {
   $scope.currentDetail = myService.values;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. As an alternative I want to reuse the OverviewController. When clicking (an running the showDetails function) the data is filled correctly, but when navigating to details the controller code is called again and the value of $scope.currentDetail is undefined again. Any idea about that?

Comment: @Paul, if you have saved data to sharedService, you can get necessary value from it. When you will pass on detail view page from overview page, you get data from shared service, like at my answer's example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. I am just looking for an alternative approach but I will put this in another question... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$scope is specific only to the specific controller. So each controller will have its own scope variable. If you want to share data across controller use a service like below.

```
shop.controller('OverviewController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Overview', function($scope, $location, Overview, detailService){

    $scope.overview = Overview.get();
    $scope.showDetails = function(product){
        $scope.currentDetail = me.details = product;
        $location.path("/productDetail");
    }
}
]);

shop.controller('DetailController', ['$scope', function($scope, detailService){
    $scope.currentDetail = detailService.details;
    console.log($scope.currentDetail);
}
]);

shop.service('detailService', function(){
  var me = this;
  me.details = {};
  return this;
});
```